# opencv 3.1 + opencv_contrib cmake configuration error

Tags: opencv, cmake

I am trying to configure cmake for opencv 3.1 + opencv_contrib 3.1.
I have downloaded both source files and extract them to respective directory in order to build and use in both c++ and python based applications.
installation. After running the following command:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv/opencv_contrib/modules \
-D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

I have run into this problem: ocv_append_source_files_cxx_compiler_options
The log of cmake is:

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.2.0
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.2.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detected version of GNU GCC: 70 (700)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_W
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_W - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_W
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_W - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WALL
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WALL - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WALL
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WALL - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_ADDRESS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_ADDRESS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_ADDRESS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_ADDRESS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WFORMAT
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WFORMAT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WINIT_SELF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WINIT_SELF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WINIT_SELF
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WINIT_SELF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WPOINTER_ARITH
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WPOINTER_ARITH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WPOINTER_ARITH
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WPOINTER_ARITH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSIGN_PROMO - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_NARROWING
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_NARROWING - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_NARROWING
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_NARROWING - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_LONG_LONG
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_LONG_LONG - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_LONG_LONG
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_LONG_LONG - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_PTHREAD - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_PTHREAD - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE2
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE2
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_AVX
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_AVX - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_AVX
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_AVX - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE3
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE3
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_SSSE3
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_SSSE3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_SSSE3
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_SSSE3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_SSE4_1
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_SSE4_1 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_SSE4_1
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_SSE4_1 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_SSE4_2
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_SSE4_2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_SSE4_2
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_SSE4_2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN - Failed
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found suitable version "1.2.11", minimum required is "1.2.3") 
-- Found TIFF: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (found version "4.0.8") 
-- Found JPEG: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so  
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_VARIABLE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_VARIABLE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_FUNCTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_FUNCTION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MAYBE_UNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MAYBE_UNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Could NOT find Jasper (missing: JASPER_LIBRARIES JASPER_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_IMPLICIT_FUNCTION_DECLARATION
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_IMPLICIT_FUNCTION_DECLARATION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_PARAMETER
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_PARAMETER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_STRICT_OVERFLOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_STRICT_OVERFLOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER - Success
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.11") 
-- Found PNG: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (found version "1.6.34") 
-- Looking for /usr/include/libpng/png.h
-- Looking for /usr/include/libpng/png.h - found
-- Found OpenEXR: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so
-- Checking for module 'gtk+-3.0'
--   Found gtk+-3.0, version 3.22.25
-- Checking for module 'gthread-2.0'
--   Found gthread-2.0, version 2.54.1
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-base-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-video-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-video-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-app-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-riff-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-base-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-video-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-video-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-app-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-riff-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'libdc1394-2'
--   Found libdc1394-2, version 2.2.5
-- Checking for module 'libv4l1'
--   Found libv4l1, version 1.12.5
-- Checking for module 'libv4l2'
--   Found libv4l2, version 1.12.5
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h - not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
-- Checking for module 'libavcodec'
--   Found libavcodec, version 57.89.100
-- Checking for module 'libavformat'
--   Found libavformat, version 57.71.100
-- Checking for module 'libavutil'
--   Found libavutil, version 55.58.100
-- Checking for module 'libswscale'
--   Found libswscale, version 4.6.100
-- Checking for module 'libavresample'
--   Found libavresample, version 3.5.0
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h - found
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h - not found
-- Checking for module 'libgphoto2'
--   Found libgphoto2, version 2.5.14
-- ICV: Downloading ippicv_linux_20151201.tgz...
-- ICV: Unpacking ippicv_linux_20151201.tgz to /home/hd/opencv/opencv-3.1.0/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack...
-- ICV: Package successfully downloaded
-- found IPP (ICV version): 9.0.1 [9.0.1]
-- at: /home/hd/opencv/opencv-3.1.0/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_lnx
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing: DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
-- To enable PlantUML support, set PLANTUML_JAR environment variable or pass -DPLANTUML_JAR=<filepath> option to cmake
-- Found PythonInterp: /home/hd/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python (found suitable version "2.7.14", minimum required is "2.7") 
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (found suitable exact version "2.7.14") 
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found suitable version "3.6.3", minimum required is "3.4") 
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so (found suitable exact version "3.6.3") 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
-- Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
-- Could NOT find Matlab (missing: MATLAB_MEX_SCRIPT MATLAB_INCLUDE_DIRS MATLAB_ROOT_DIR MATLAB_LIBRARIES MATLAB_LIBRARY_DIRS MATLAB_MEXEXT MATLAB_ARCH MATLAB_BIN) 
-- VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHADOW - Success
-- Caffe:   NO
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake:429 (message):
  Protobuf compiler version doesn't match library version 3.0.0
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/hd/opencv/opencv_contrib/modules/cnn_3dobj/CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package)


-- Found Protobuf: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so (found version "3.0.0") 
-- Protobuf:   YES
-- Glog:   NO
CMake Error at /home/hd/opencv/opencv_contrib/modules/datasets/CMakeLists.txt:5 (ocv_append_source_files_cxx_compiler_options):
  Unknown CMake command "ocv_append_source_files_cxx_compiler_options".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/hd/opencv/opencv-3.1.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/hd/opencv/opencv-3.1.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

What could be the reason behind such error?

Comment: What compiler are you using?